# Can Xamarin Forms target iOS Universal Apps?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Is there any way to create a Xamarin Forms app targeting iOS Universal Apps like you can with Xamarin?

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/getting_started/hello,_ipad___universal_apps/

If not what is the best way to handle targeting both iPhone and iPad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I've been leveragign the Device.Idiom functionality.

We're using MVVM light, so I have a common ViewModel and I've extended the INavigation Service so that i can configure it with both a Phone & Tablet page.

Then when I call

```
_navigationService.NavigateTo(PageKey, ViewModel);
```

The navgiation service will lookup the key in the configuration dictionary, and decide based on the idiom (Phone / Tablet) whether to the return the PhoneVersion or TabletVersion of the page.

http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/working-with/platform-specifics/

Comment: Sounds like a good approach. I'm using MvvmCross but should be able to do exactly the same.